# SELECT statement needs to output value conditional on NULL data

Tags: sql-server-2008

It was hard to condense in the title what I need... Here it goes. This is for SQL Server 2008.

For a reason that is too long to explain here, I need to have a SELECT statements that will display, among other columns, a value of 1 if 4 columns have a value null. Something like this.

```
SELECT name, lastname, p1, p2, p3, p4, "1 if p1,p2,p3 and p4 are all NULL, 0 otherwise" city, st, zip
FROM mytable
```

The questions is how to I translate to code this: **"1 if p1,p2,p3 and p4 are all NULL, 0 otherwise"** ?

I tried

```
CASE len(p1+p2+p3+p4) WHEN NULL 1 ELSE 0 END
```

But it didn't work. even though when I do

```
SELECT len(p1+p2+p3+p4) FROM mytable
```

The result iS NULL.

I tried IF ELSE, but it doesn't seem to be welcome in a SELECT statement.

Ideas?

Thanks.

---

Thanks guys.
I chose the answer that doesn't use COALESCE because it's the one I understood. I tried reading MS's explanation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx and I still didn't fully understand, plus the note saying that "At least one of the null values must be a typed NULL" scared me off a bit.
Thanks to all.

---

Comment: Are p1-p4 all the same data type?

Comment: you should avoid those `p1+p2+p3+p4` if you are not validating the null fields, any math operation over `NULL` is null, so 1000+`null`= `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    SELECT name, lastname, 
CASE WHEN  (p1 is null and p2 is null and p3 is null and p4 is null) then 1 
else 0 end , city, st, zip
    FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name, lastname, p1, p2, p3, p4, CASE WHEN COALESCE(p1, p2, p3, p4) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS nulltest, city, state, zip
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select case
   coalesce(null,null,null,null,'X') 
   when 'X' then 1
   else 0
   end
```